# i18next-xhr-backend fallback to load local resources after network error in react application

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I'm using i18n for translation in my react application I would like to call translation from my server and If I can not load them because of error (500, 404..) I need to redirect call to my local resources with translations.

i18n.ts file

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import XHR from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import axios from 'axios';

const languages = ['de', 'en'];
const translationsURL = 'http://server.resources.eu';
const translationsLocals = '/translations/{{lng}}.json';

const loadCurrent = (url: string, options: any, callback: any, data: any) => {
  axios
    .get(url)
    .then((res: any) => {
      callback(res.data, { status: res.status });
    });
};

i18n
  .use(XHR)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    backend: {
      loadPath: translationsURL,
      parse(data: any) {
        return data;
      },
      ajax: loadCurrent,
    },
    debug: false,
    whitelist: languages,
  });

export default i18n;
```

As you can see I want to change translationsURL to translationsLocals when error will acccure.

Comment: Where are your local resources?

Comment: public/translations/.., it works but I would like have `loadPath` setup dynamically to public when external resources (from endpoint) are down.

Comment: You can chain a catch statement, and your fallback call in it.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to this?